# How to map multiple different request bodies in to same POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http-post, mapping

I have different post request bodies like follows:

```
{
   "name": "US",  
   "amount": "1234"    
}

{
   "fullName": "US",  
   "transAmount": "1234"    
}
```

I have created a java filter to modify those request bodies in my spring boot application. I want to convert them in to an uniform format in order to make all the request bodies can be mapped in to same POJO.

Eventually "name" and "fullName" shold be mapped to name,
"amount" and "transAmount" should be mapped to amount. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your filter, you may populate your uniform POJO. Since attribute names are different, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JsonAlias:

```
@JsonAlias({"name", "fullName"})
private String name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at @JsonAlias [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html)

```
public class Info {
  @JsonAlias({"name", "fullName"}
  public String name;

  @JsonAlias({"amount", "transAmount"}
  public double amount;
}
```